# Matlab creates overlayed ticks when saving a plot as png

Tags: matlab, save, png

I have a problem when saving matlab timeseries plots as png. The internal matlab window shows half as many xticks as the saved image. This leads to overlayed ticklabels in the saved plot.

Here is an example minimal code:

```
data = (1:12);

time(1,:) = '10-Sep-2012 13:42:10';
time(2,:) = '10-Sep-2012 13:43:10';
time(3,:) = '10-Sep-2012 13:44:10';
time(4,:) = '10-Sep-2012 13:45:10';
time(5,:) = '10-Sep-2012 13:46:10';
time(6,:) = '10-Sep-2012 13:47:10';
time(7,:) = '10-Sep-2012 13:48:10';
time(8,:) = '10-Sep-2012 13:49:10';
time(9,:) = '10-Sep-2012 13:50:10';
time(10,:) = '10-Sep-2012 13:51:10';
time(11,:) = '10-Sep-2012 13:52:10';
time(12,:) = '10-Sep-2012 13:53:10';

ts = timeseries(data,time);
ts.TimeInfo.Format = 'dd, HH:MM:SS';

figure(1)
plot(ts);

%saveas(gca, 'tickmovetest', 'png')
print(gcf, '-dpng', 'tickmovetest')
```

It does not matter wether I use the plot or the saveas command. data is just random numbers, time is a vector of equal length containing strings like '10-Sep-2012 13:42:10'.

Has anyone experienced the problem and found an answer?
It would be great if matlab would just retain the number of ticks it had before saving the plot.

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example, which I could copy/paste to reproduce your error?

Comment: Hi Schorsch, thanks for your reply. I was away for a while, sorry for my late reply. I added a few lines to make the code snippet more convenient. Johannes

Answer (score 0):

Matlab re-sizes the figure when you save it. If you do not explicitly specify where you want your tick-marks and -labels, you might end up with overlapping labels.
That being said, there are two options:

1. Manually set your tick-positions and tick-labels.
2. There is a contribution on the Matlab File Exchange, called [`saveSamesize`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17868-savesamesize) which saves the figure at exactly the same size as it appears on screen. (It works with R2013a).
   With the example above, you would call it as follows:

   ```
   saveSameSize(gcf, 'format', 'png', 'file', 'tickmovetest.png');
   ```

My recommendation would be to actively set the tick-positions and -labels to avoid any surprises.

PS
Your example does not generate overlapping labels for me, however, this `print`-command does:

```
print(gcf, '-dpng','-r200','tickmovetest')
```

Comment: Thank you Schorsch! I will look into saveSameSize, it looks promising. And it is good to know that this is a common problem. Thanks!